# select all rows that have more than two matching composite keys in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

[mysql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ce5c3/24)

I have a composite table and I'm trying to select rows that has both 1 and 2 in pk2 column. As you can see, I've successfully could write a query that does the job by using JOIN... Yeah. It's okay but not satisfying.

I'm afraid if this code will get messy and slower by adding more JOINs in the query when it needs more than 10 constraints.

Is there a faster & cleaner way to get the same result?

**Assumption:**

There can be more than 10 constraints in the worst scenario. Unlikely but possibly.

**What I've tried so far:**

1. I tried using UNION  but didn't work & thought it's one of the worst options to choose when it comes to performance efficiency.
2. I tried WHERE IN (....)  but it's just same as WHERE  A or B... which is not what I intended.
3. I tried subquerying in FROM clause... but the more constraints it has, the worse nightmare it becomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a "set-within-sets" query.  I like to approach it with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.  This provides flexible logic for handling many different situations:

```
SELECT t1.pk1
FROM t1
WHERE pk2 IN (1, 2)
GROUP by t1.pk1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

This assumes that the rows in the table are unique (otherwise use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ce5c3/25) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Holy moly,  didn't expect it to be answered this soon.

Comment: Never knew about HAVING before I confirmed it's working and understand how it works now :)  I will select it as an answer after 11 mins.  It seems like I cannot mark it before the time.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to group by `pk1` and count the distinct `pk2` values. E.g.:

```
SELECT   pk1
FROM     t1
WHERE    pk2 IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY pk1
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT pk2) = 2
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ce5c3/30/0)**

Comment: Nice variation. Thanks !